# Index for bit comparisons in postgreSQL (and other databases)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, boolean, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to speed up lookups like the following by an index on `flags`, where `5` could be any number?

```
select * from user where flags & 5 > 0
```

`flags` is an integer column and the idea behind this is to store different boolean attributes in one column. So for this examples it might be:

```
flags bit | 1        | 2      | 4                     | 8        | ...
meaning   | is admin | banned | password needs change | whatever | ...
```

So a user who is admin and whose password needs to be changed can be found by the above select statement (even if he has other flags set, too).

For postgreSQL I could add an expression index like this for the above query:

```
create index index_name on user ((flags & 5 > 0))
```

But then I'd have to create an index for every combination of flags, because the above index works only for value `flags & 5`.

So is there an index to speed up `flags & any_number > 0`?

<sup>I know I could use different boolean columns for each flag (feels messy for me having > 50 flags) or postgreSQL bit data type (for which there is an index type I assume), but I'm specially interested if there's a way to have an index for the above use case on an integer column.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The bit datatype is intended for saving multiple bits in a single column, so that would be more appropriate than using a numeric type.

You could probably index on an expression:

```
create index index_my_table_is_admin
on my_table (case flags & 5 when 0 then false else true end)
```

And then query:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  (case flags & 5 when 0 then false else true end) = 't';
```

But I'd be inclined to create a view:

```
create view ...
as
select ...
       (case flags & 5 when 0 then false else true end) is_admin
       ...
from   my_table;
```

It's an interesting intellectual exercise I guess, but I'd just use a set of booleans.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the way to index in postgreSQL can be `create index index_name on user ((flags & 5 > 0))` - or am I wrong? Then the select could simply be like in my question (no need for `case`, easier syntax).